# Unity C#. Code is executing with delay (I guess?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, the i want to make a particles when the player is walking. But there's a problem:
My player moves - there is no particle code executing, BUT when he's stops - the particles are appear and after some period of time, they're destroying with the duration i set in Unity's Inspector.
BUT! When i start moving the player during the particles appear duration, they're no longer destroying themselves untill the player stops.
Code for particles:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticleOfSteps : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem collectParticle;
    public Vector3 playerMovement;
    //public Vector3 oldRotationPosition;
    private GameObject Player;
    public float cor = 0.1f;
    private void Start()
    {
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        playerMovement = Player.transform.position;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
        if (playerMovement != Player.transform.localPosition)
        {
            Collect();
        }

       
    }
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
    }
    public void Collect()
    {
        StartCoroutine(delayForPlayer());
    }
    public IEnumerator delayForPlayer()
    {
        playerMovement = Player.transform.localPosition;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
        collectParticle.Play();
        Debug.Log("2");
    }
}
```

as you can see, i tried lots of things. Even using LateUpdate for playerMovement = Player.transform.localPosition; (Like it'd help me, yes)
I used WaitForSeconds() func, because i had thought that the problem was in updating coordinates of playerMovement, but it didn't helped me.

Again: i need particles to appear when the player is moving. Please, help!

Comment: so you put in a delay and then wonder why its delayed?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I meant not "Delayed" for the exact period of time, it's delayed untill the "W" button(for walking forward), or "S" (For going back) are up. Then the particles appear.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. But it sounds like you know what you need you just havent done it yet

Comment: Can you post the code of the player where he presses W or S and how it influences the particles?